# Body com height 100% não funciona com div height auto dentro

Tags: html, css, height

Meu CSS:

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;

}
html {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
body {
 height: 100%; /* 707.38px */
 width: 100%;
 background-image: url('../_img/bg.jpg');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   /*overflow: hidden;
   overflow: auto;*/
}
.conteudo {
 height: 72%;
 width: 60%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
 text-align: center;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: absolute;
 border-radius: 7px;
}
#login {
 width: 30%;
 height: auto;
 animation: fadein 1.5s;
}
img.logo {
 width: 55%;
}
input {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 20px; /* 22px */
 padding: 1.8% 1.5%; /* 7px 5px*/
 margin: 1.11%; /* 5px */
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #343535;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 color: #fff;
}
input.login {
 width: 75%;
}
button {
 font-size: 20px; /* 22px */
 padding: 2.222222222222222% 1.111111111111111%; /* 10px 5px */
 margin: 3.5%; /* 10px */
 background-color: #2679ac;
 color: white;
 border-radius: 7px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
button.login {
 width: 27%;
}
button:hover {
 background-color: #195070;
 transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
#login {
 width: 35%;
}
}

Meu HTML:
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>True Work</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/style.css">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 </head>
  
 <body>
  
  <div id="loader" class="loader"></div>
  <div id="login" class="conteudo">
   <img class="logo" src="https://www.twpro.solutions/_img/logo.png" alt="Logotipo">

   <form method="POST" action="_classes/valida_login.php">
    <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario" class="login" required="">
    <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" class="login" required="">
    <button type="submit" class="login">Entrar</button>
   </form>
  </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Boa tarde,

Já andei pesquisando em diversos locais e nenhuma das soluções me ajudaram, minha questão é a seguinte: Tenho uma pagina de login,nela contém uma div centralizada com **Height: auto** e apenas isso, porém ao definir o Body como **Height: 100%**, este simplesmente **não** surte efeitos.

Ps.: Testei sem a div (body vazio), e funcionou perfeitamente, só na presença da div que não tem efeitos. Pode parecer um problema básico de iniciante, mas estou batendo a cabeça alguns dias e realmente não consegui nenhuma das soluções que me apresentaram

[image: Meu problema: O Body deveria ocupar toda a **página**, e não somente a tela]

Site para testes: https://www.twpro.solutions/index.php

Comment: Jovem por favos use o link para editar logo abaixo da sua pergunta e inclua nela seu HTML e CSS. Mas de ante mão verifique se seu documento tem essa tag logo no início `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Vc quer que o box preto ocupe 100% da altura da página é isso:?

Comment: Desculpe, sou usuário novo por aqui rsrs

Comment: Não to entendendo o seu problema com o código, coloquei #login com  height: 100% e foi normal

Comment: Na verdade o problema não é com #login, e sim com o body, ele ocupa a tela toda, porém em telas menores (onde há barra de rolagem) o body não se estende até o final da pagina.

Comment: Entendi... mas aqui testando pelo Chrome Dev Tools ele está indo até o final, mesmo em telas bem pequenas...

Comment: Acabei de adicionar o print do meu problema, me desculpe se estou fazendo alguma coisa errada, postando ou comentando de forma indevida, nunca usei um fórum rsrs

Comment: Aqui está normal ainda ... https://imgur.com/a/g5VxLDj

Comment: coloca um float:left; no  html e no  body

Comment: Marcos: Ainda não funcionou :/
Hugo: Minimiza a tela, de forma a mostrar a scroll vertical, igual o print está na pergunta

Comment: olha ai... https://imgur.com/PP1F21Z

Comment: Exato Hugo, mas ao rolar a página pra baixo, você ve que o body não continua

Comment: Seu site vai ser acessado por Apple Whatch ou algum Smart Whatch? Se não vc não precisa se preocupar, não vai existir usuário como essa resolução de tela... A não ser que seu problema seja com algum validador de código acusando algum erro...

Comment: Na verdade estou com problema no Android, quando o teclado sobe, o height do body sobe junto, causando problemas com elementos posicionados com Bottom: 0

Comment: Hugo: https://imgur.com/a/qmJr3mh;

Quando o teclado do android sobre, o texto sobrepõe o botão de Login, o que incomoda bastante o cliente.

Comment: Alguma sugestão ?